# How to enter a while loop unless three conditions succeed simultaneously

Tags: while-loop, conditional-statements, octave

I'm trying to create a complex condition consisting of three smaller conditions, to be used in a while loop. I always want to enter the loop except when all three conditions are met simultenously. The way I have it now, if only one of these meet, the loop exits. I want it to exit only when they meet at the same time instead. Here's what I have:

```
while (a!=1) && (b!=2) && (c!=5)
  disp(a);
  disp(b);
  disp(c);
endwhile
```

So, if a is 1, b is 2, and c is 5, I don't want to enter the loop.
But if a is 2, b is 3, and c is 5, I *do* want to enter the loop, but this isn't what's happening with my code.

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Perhaps you could clarify, provide a more complete example? Or tell us what you expect to happen vs what is actually happening?

Comment: Take a step back.  This `while` loop will keep iterating until `a == 1`, `b == 2` or `c == 5`.  Is that the desired outcome?  It's a bit hard to determine this from your question.  Please modify your question to state what you are specifically trying to accomplish, not show what you want to accomplish with your (possibly broken) code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have add edit explain I hope to be clear

Comment: It's still very unclear. Can you show some numerical examples of a, b and c and when it should and shouldn't enter the loop?

Comment: I think you have some basic misconception how boolean algebra works, see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws Please try to describe your question better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to say you want the while loop to proceed *except* in the specific scenario that a=1, b=2, and c=5 (as opposed to just one of them having that value).

Therefore the correct statement that you're trying to relay is "proceed when (a==1 && b == 2 && c==5) is *false*" i.e.

```
while !(a==1 && b==2 && c==5)
  % do stuff
endwhile
```

Note that what you wrote isn't equivalent. 
Have a look at [De Morgan's laws](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/deMorgansLaws.html). Basically they say that:

> 1. *not* (A ***and*** B ***and*** C)  =  (*not* A) ***or*** (*not* B) ***or*** (*not* C)
> 2. *not* (A ***or*** B ***or*** C)   =  (*not* A) ***and*** (*not* B) ***and*** (*not* C)

Therefore `(a!=1 && b!=2 && c!=5)` is NOT the same as `!(a==1 && b == 2 && c==5)`.
Instead it's the same as `!(a==1 || b == 2 || c==5)`

---

PS. Another way to do this, which may be a bit clearer to read:

```
while true                   % i.e. loop forever

  if a==1 && b==2 && c==5
    break;                   % i.e. exit loop if this condition is true
  end  

  % do stuff
end
```

Comment: YES! This works, then correct way is set ! outside instead of use !=. Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome. If you don't mind, I will edit your question and title a bit to make it more useful / searchable / relevant to future readers. :)